# Removing gaps between .png image buttons Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am making a game and I need to place a bunch of buttons next to each other (without a tiny gap in between each button). Is the a way to remove the spaces between these buttons in tkinter? thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
square_1_button=Button(root, image = T4S,borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0,relief=FLAT)
square_1_button.bind("<Button-1>", play_square_1)
square_1_button.grid(row=2,column=12)
```

Location of the problem:
[image: location of the problem]

Comment: The "location of the problem" image is a screenshot of idle 3.6.3 running my script

Comment: try with `Label` instead of `Button`

Comment: `grid` has options for padding. It might be that on your system it defaults to 1 pixel. Have you tried explicitly setting the padding to zero?

Comment: @BryanOakley i tried but it didn't work. I managed to fix my problem with the answer of furas. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can not reproduce the behaviour in Windows7, Python 3.6 and TK / Tcl 8.6